# 'type' object is not subscriptable using for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
l=[]
  for i in the range[4]:
    l.append(i)
  return(l)
```

I am getting the error while trying to append the numbers through 0 to 4 to a list(l).

Comment: the brackets don't match. Stop using notepad++ as your editor if you are beginner. Install a real IDE.

Comment: The brackets are still incorrect. You need to use circular brackets. Range is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. The problem is the range.

Change it to e.g.

```
for i in the range(0,4):
    l.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's already answered, but this can be kept as a simple oneLiner as well

```
l = []
output = [i for i in range(4)]
# Returns: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```